# Combinaciones de teclado en MAC OSX

Tags: macos, vscode

estoy migrando a MAC, pero no en cuentro la forma de usar atajos de teclado,

algunos ya los encontrado, pero me falta una de las mejores, es el de

`CONTROL + ESPACIO`, la cual lista los parámetros, propiedades, etc.

Actualmente estoy en `VS Code` pero no funciona, no creo que sea por el editor, esta accion funciona normal en `Sublime text, android studio, etc` incluido `VS Code` pero no logro hacer esta combinación en `MAC`

Comment: Recuerda que `CONTROL` en mac es `Command` Y `Alt` es `Option` [Métodos abreviados](https://tecnoloco.istocks.club/metodos-abreviados-de-teclado-esenciales-para-visual-studio-code/2020-05-30/)

Comment: @JoséVásquez , lo sé pero `COMMAND + ESPACIO` me muestra un buscador general en el equipo, y no la las propiedades de la clase, que sale en `windows o linux`